# Qual a diferença entre as seguintes formas de utilização dos métodos ON e OFF do jQuery

Tags: jquery

1 - Costumava útilizar desta forma:

```
$(document).off('evento', 'elemento', nomeFuncao);
$(document).on('evento', 'elemento', nomeFuncao);
```

2 - Mas recentemente utilizei assim e funcionou da mesma forma.

```
$(document).off().on('evento', 'elemento', function() {});
```

No segundo exemplo eu não utilizei nenhum tipo de identificador para o método off. Mas mesmo assim ele removeu apenas o evento correto do obj document.

Gostaria de saber se a segunda forma de utilização está correta também. Ou se é uma prática ruim?

Comment: `Off` não conheço e nunca usei, e eu utilizo `On` é um `Bind`. Exemplo `$('div#botao').on('click', function() { alert(1); });` ou `$('div#botao').bind('click', function() { alert(2); });` ... veja o teste: http://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/OXoVVB

Comment: Sim. Mas a partir da versão 1.7 do jQuery ele recomenda a útilização do método ON para adicionar manipuladores de eventos ao document. O método BIND deve ser usado apenas em verões anteriores a 1.7 do jQuery.
Referencia: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Entendo, e pesquisei sobre `off()` é igual `unbind()`, mas tem problema sua versão anterior? e porque não utiliza javascript puro rss

Comment: Pelo que eu li na documentação. bind() e unbind() foram substituidos pelos métodos on e off a partir da versão 1.7 do jQuery. 
Com relação ao porque eu não fiz com javascript puro, é porque eu não sei como fazer a mesma coisa com javascript puro. 
Eu acho bem prático e simples com jQuery. Mas se você acha que é mais simples com javascript, eu ficaria feliz se você pudesse me mostrar um exemplo. ;)

Comment: Vish!! Eu usava javascript pure até angular mais pratico kkkk, bind é igual addEventListener de javascript puro, nada fácil e vários tipo de elemento e objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `.off()` é utilizado principalmente para impedir duplicação de uma mesma ação, veja o exemplo, SEM `.off()`:

```js
function button(e){

  if($(e).hasClass('comOff')){
    $(e).off();
  }
  
  $(e).on('click', function() {
        button($(this));
        alert($(this).text());
  });

}


button('.semOff');
button('.comOff');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="semOff">SEM OFF</button>
<br>
<hr>
<button class="comOff">COM OFF</button>
```

Neste exemplo, que não é um dos melhores, quando clica em "SEM OFF" mais de uma vez irá exibir mais de um alerta. Isso ocorre porque a ação anterior não foi desligada, assim irá adicionada mais uma.  Quando utiliza o `.off()` você irá remover qualquer `.on()` que foi adicionado anteriormente.

Quando você utiliza: `$(document).off()`, significa que TODOS os `.on()` aplicados no `document` serão removidos, quando você especifica `$(document).off('evento', 'elemento', nomeFuncao);` você apenas esse será removido!

Essa é a diferença.

*Particularmente prefiro por usar `$('div button.salvar').on('click', [...])` por exemplo, ao invés de usar o `document`.*

Comment: Eu não sei ao certo se existe alguma diferença entre adicionar no document ou diretamente no elemento. Mas eu utilizei da seguinte forma: $(document).off('change', '#modulo').on('change', '#modulo', function() { //codigo }); e ele removel apenas o evento delegado ao id modulo. Mantendo todos os outros eventos que eu havia adicionado. Então acho que não faz diferença adicioná-lo no document ou no elemento. Vou pesquisar mais e tentar descobrir se existe alguma diferença!

Answer (score 5):

Sim, a segunda forma está correta, conforme a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/off/). Ela remove **todos** os *listeners* de eventos do elemento que tiverem sido adicionados com `on` – no caso do seu exemplo, todos os listeners do `document` serão removidos.